# Implementing different leaf and folder context menus for YUI treeview

Tags: javascript, treeview, yui

I implemented a treeview with context menus. I would like to have two sepearate context menus with different options, one for folders and the other for leaves.

My tree is built from a nested html tree. Since I am building this tree using a mako template, I know which nodes are trees and folders. Each node is either a `<li class="folder">` or `.

I am currently using `oFolderContextMenu.cfg.setProperty("trigger", YAHOO.util.Dom.getElementsByClassName("folder"));` but the problem is that only top level folders have context menus.

I would like the subfolders to also have the menus. Folders and subfolders all have the "folder" class. I also tried setting the trigger in the oFolderContextMenu definition but end up with the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can collect all your DOM elements which you want to use as trigger into an array and then pass them to the configuration. With the native function "concat" you can join one ore more arrays into one.

example:

```
var triggerNodes, foldernodes, folder;
foldernodes = YAHOO.util.Dom.getElementsByClassName("foldernode");
folder = YAHOO.util.Dom.getElementsByClassName("folder");
triggerNodes = foldernodes.concat(folder);

oFolderContextMenu.cfg.setProperty("trigger", triggerNodes);
```

concat documentation - http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_concat_array.asp

Comment: Sorry, my example was wrong. I only have one class for folder, "folder". I think the issue is how the Treeview nodes are being loaded.

Comment: Ok, i can imagine that you have a timing problem. Try to check that all your folder elements are the DOM when you call getElementsByClassName.

Comment: I think it's a timing problem too. I have all of the folder elements if I do the getElementsByClassName before the Treeview is rendered. I am saving them as a global variable and tried passing that to the "trigger" property in the context menu definiition. Same problem.